# JQuery - ASP.NET and JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Do I need to remove code-behind *.cs files to use JQuery with ASP.NET?

If yes, why should I do that?

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this? It's a genuine question, not everyone knows everything, regardless of how simple the question/answer.

Answer (score 8):

**NO.**

Code behind is server-side, jQuery is client side.  They are two **entirely** different worlds.  There should be no reason why you would need to remove the .cs files.

Answer (score 0):

Code behind doesn't have anything to do with jQuery, and can't affect it.

jQuery is a JavaScript library, you have to put your code that uses it in your .aspx files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove code-behind files.

JQuery is just a javascript library.

Do you need to remove javascript files? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No, you just have to add jQuery to the .aspx file (or it's master page).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

And you can use it! :)